# HTML Table is not clearing completely

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using bootstrapTable or dataTable to generate a table. This table has the content filled using GET METHOD, a button is there to fill a new contents, so a empty the previous data and write the new.

That's where the problem shows up. The BootstrapTable or DataTable has a footer description showing the sum of rows. I noted when I write the new data they sums up with the previous content. Used `$("#table1).html("")` the clear this previous data and write the new.

What happened was, the table was "clear", technically, on page view, but the footer description shows previous data, like this `Showing 1 to 10 of 66 entries` and access the source-view all rows was still there.

Example:

```
<table id="table1"> 
  <thead>
    <th> HEAD 1</th>
    <th> HEAD 2</th>
    <th> HEAD 3</th>
    <th> HEAD 4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Baar 1 </td>
      <td>  Baar 1 </td>
      <td>  Baar 1</td>
      <td>  Baar 1</td>
      <td>  Baar 1</td>      
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>  Baar 2</td>
      <td>  Baar 2 </td>
      <td>  Baar 2</td>
      <td>  Baar 2</td>
      <td>  Baar 2</td>      
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td> Baar 3 </td>
      <td>Baar 3 </td>
      <td> Baar 3</td>
      <td> Baar 3</td>
      <td> Baar 3</td>      
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Running `html("")` this is what I expected

```
<table id="table1"> 
  <thead>
    <th> HEAD 1</th>
    <th> HEAD 2</th>
    <th> HEAD 3</th>
    <th> HEAD 4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

For testing, but a button

`<button name='button'>Click Here</button>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[name=button]').on('click',function(){
        $('#table1 tbody').html("");
    });

});
```

Already tested: `empty()` and `remove()`

Comment: For DataTables, why not use the `destroy()` or `clear()` methods? https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

Comment: Also, `$('#table1 tbody').html("");` only clears tbody, not the footer (which would be `tfoot`)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the footer description won't update unless something specifically tells it to. Your jquery doesn't appear to update that data when the button is clicked. Also, if you mean you're viewing source on the web page itself, nothing gets manipulated there, you would need to use the browser's inspector which will show you any DOM manipulation that jquery/javascript does.

Comment: OK, only clear tbody, I used the footer as reference, showing which the data was not clear. the view-source the data keeps there

Comment: I thought that when I clear tbody, the view page is OK, is clear, but `CTRL + U`, view-source, the data is there.. is right?

Comment: Yeah, CTRL + U will show you the original HTML source code that is not changed by js/jquery. To see changes to the DOM, you would have to use the inspector built into the browser.

Comment: How to clear that footer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're footer description is called, but assuming it's a unique id, it would be something like $('#footer-description').html(); You can also put in the new amount doing something like $('#footer-description').html('Showing x - y of ' + $('#table1 tbody tr').length); If the count is zero, you would want a special message for that. You would have to make all of the changes to select your footer description and make sure you're getting the length of the elements you're trying to count. I'm assuming the rows in the table are the entries you're counting, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I used  the datatable functions `clear()` and `draw()` aaand worked. Thanks :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Vadivel123/db3cL41k/